# Rearrange list in-place by modifying the original list, put even-index values at front

Tags: python, list, slice, indices, in-place

I am relatively new to python and I am still trying to learn the basics of the language. I stumbled upon a question which asks you to rearrange the list by modifying the original. What you are supposed to do is move all the even index values to the front (in reverse order) followed by the odd index values.

Example:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l = [6, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 5]
```

My initial approach was to just use the following:

```
l = l[::-2] + l[1::2]
```

However, apparently this is considered 'creating a new list' rather than looping through the original list to modify it.

As such, I was hoping to get some ideas or hints as to how I should approach this particular question. I know that I can use a for loop or a while loop to cycle through the elements / index, but I don't know how to do a swap or anything else for that matter.

Comment: "_I don't know how to do a swap_": Learning how to do this is a good starting point. Consult your Python book or tutor.

Comment: Swaps are easy in Python: `x, y = y, z`. It works with list indexes, too: `l[x], l[y] = l[y], l[x]`

Comment: Btw `l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` is a terrible example, since the values are identical to the indices.

Comment: Edit: you can't avoid copying if you do a sort/sort-in-place, because you need a custom sort function which compares oddness/evenness of indices (not values). So a sort function would need to accept a tuple of (index, value), generated with enumerate(l). But that's a copy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by assigning to a list slice instead of a variable:

```
l[:] = l[::2][::-1] + l[1::2]
```

Your expression for the reversed even elements was also wrong. Use `l[::2]` to get all the even numbers, then reverse that with `[::-1]`.

This is effectively equivalent to:

```
templ = l[::2][::-1] + l[1::2]
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = templ[i]
```

The `for` loop modifies the original list in place.

Comment: This _still_ creates a new list, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you, but I feel like at this point that would defeat the purpose of the question in itself.

Comment: @DyZ as intermediate variable yes, but the reference `l` doesn't change. It is only mutated.

Comment: @NaumanShahid The usual purpose of modifying the original list is so that all the variables that refer to it will see the changes. This does that.

Comment: @Julien I perfectly see your point, but as a teacher, I would not accept this as a solution.

Comment: @Barmar Another purpose is not to create a copy of a list that is already too large.

Comment: @Julien This is a typical algorithmic exercise.

Comment: @Barmar I am sorry, I overlooked the `[:]`. My bad. Let's clean the junk.

Comment: Pardon me if I'm mistaking something but your output is different from OP's expected output.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I didn't even check that his expression for the result was correct, I was fixated on the problem of modifying in place. I've fixed that now.

Comment: @DyZ I deleted my responses, the ball is in your court.

Comment: I deleted everything that was worth deleting. I still stand my ground: this is not the "right" solution. Besides, it fails for a list with an odd number of items. Try `l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8]`.

Comment: Hint: `l[::2][::-1] + l[1::2]` :)

Comment: @DyZ Thanks. You're probably right that the instructor really wanted everything done by swapping elements within the list (i.e. it uses O(1) space rather than O(n) space). If so, the question needs to be more specific. Feel free to post a better answer.